# Yii2 how does search() in SearchModel work?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Please can someone explain how the `search` method in a Yii2 `SearchModel` works? I generated it using Gii. Here it is:

```
public function search($params){
    $query = MyModel::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $this->addCondition($query, 'att1');
    $this->addCondition($query, 'att1', true);
    $this->addCondition($query, 'att2');
    $this->addCondition($query, 'att2', true);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
$search = new MyModelSearch();
$myModels = $search->search(['att3' => '3']);
```

Regardless of what attributes I use in calling `search`, I always get back the same result - i.e. all the entries in the table. I'm missing something here that I just do not understand.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `search()` function generated by *Gii* use [`ActiveRecord::load()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail) to set search parameters :

> `load()` gets the `'FormName'` from the model's `formName()` method (which you may override), unless the `$formName` parameter is given. If the form name is empty, `load()` populates the model with the whole of `$data`, instead of `$data['FormName']`.

So you should try :

```
$myModels = $search->search(['MyModelSearch'=>['att3'=>3]]);
```

Or

```
$myModels = $search->search([$search->formName()=>['att3'=>3]]);
```

And of course add a condition on `att3` attribute in `search()` function :

```
$this->addCondition($query, 'att3');
```

But if you really want to use `$myModels = $search->search(['att3' => '3']);` then you should simply replace `$this->load($params)` with `$this->load($params, '')`.

Comment: Sometimes simple solutions work; this is one of them! :) Works perfectly.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the difference between your code and mine :
`$search = new ModelSearch(); $search->att3 = 3; $myDataProvider = $search->search('');` I also get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some additional param to pass to search() method, you can change search method like this in SomeSearch.php:

```
public function search($params, $additional=0)
{
   //...
   if($additional==1) {
       $query->andWhere(['status'=>['some', 'other']);
   }
}
```

and inside controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $searchModel = new AdminSearch();

   $additional=1;
   $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $additional);

   return $this->render('index', [
      'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $searchModel = new CursadoSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andWhere([ 'cursado.curso_id' => $curso_id]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].