# PHP, Yii2 GridView filtering on relational value

Tags: php, entity-relationship, yii2

Following on from this:

[Yii2 how does search() in SearchModel work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779085/yii2-how-does-search-in-searchmodel-work)

I would like to be able to filter a `GridView` column of relational data. This is what I mean:

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`. Both have corresponding models generated using  Gii. `TableA` has a foreign key to a value in `TableB`, like this:

```
TableA
attrA1, attrA2, attrA3, TableB.attrB1

TableB
attrB1, attrB2, attrB3
```

attrA1 and attrB1 are the primary keys of their corresponding tables.

Now, I have a Yii2 `GridView` of `attrA2`, `attrA3` and `attrB2`. I have a working filter on `attrA2` and `attrA3` so that I can search on column values. I also have a working sort for these two columns too - by just clicking on the column header. I would like to be able to add this filtering and sorting on `attrB2` too.

My `TableASearch` model looks like this:

```
public function search($params){
    $query = TableA::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $this->addCondition($query, 'attrA2');
    $this->addCondition($query, 'attrA2', true);
    $this->addCondition($query, 'attrA3');
    $this->addCondition($query, 'attrA3', true);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

In my `TableA` model, I set the related value like this

```
    public $relationalValue;

public function afterFind(){
    $b = TableB::find(['attrB1' => $this->attrB1]);
    $this->relationalValue = $b->relationalValue;
}
```

Although it is probably not the best way of doing this. I think I have to use $relationalValue somewhere in my search function but I'm not sure how. Similarly, I would like to be able to sort by this column too - just like I can for `attrA2` and `AttrA3` by clicking on the header link`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you perhaps update your question to have the searchModel reflect the latest changes to the framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering a gridview by a column is damn easy in Yii 2.0. Please add the filter attribute to a gridview column having lookup values, as under:

```
[
        "class" => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
        "attribute" => "status_id",
        'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Status::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        "value" => function($model){
            if ($rel = $model->getStatus()->one()) {
                return yii\helpers\Html::a($rel->name,["crud/status/view", 'id' => $rel->id,],["data-pjax"=>0]);
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        },
        "format" => "raw",
],
```

Comment: Only just seen this, a year on and 2 years since I asked it. This is a neat little answer and by far the easiest solution. Thank you.

Comment: its good and work for me but all result in DropDownList , how to change ajax textbox like more filter textbox???

Answer (score 24):

This is based on the description in the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data). The base code for the SearchModel comes from the Gii code generator. This is also assuming that $this->TableB has been setup using `hasOne()` or `hasMany()` relation. See this [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data).

**1. Setup search model**

In `TableASearch` model add:

```
public function attributes()
{
    // add related fields to searchable attributes
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['TableB.attrB1']);
}

public function rules() 
{
    return [
        /* your other rules */
        [['TableB.attrB1'], 'safe']
    ];
}
```

Then in `TableASearch->search()` add (before `$this->load()`):

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['TableB.attrB1'] = [
      'asc' => ['TableB.attrB1' => SORT_ASC],
      'desc' => ['TableB.attrB1' => SORT_DESC],
 ];

$query->joinWith(['TableB']);
```

Then the actual search of your data (below `$this->load()`):

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'like',
    'TableB.attrB1',
     $this->getAttribute('TableB.attrB1')
]);
```

**2. Configure `GridView`**

Add to your view:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        /* Other columns */
       'TableB1.attrB1',
        /* Other columns */        
     ]
]);
```

Comment: `$query->joinWith(['companyPosition']);`
should be
`$query->joinWith(['TableB']);`

Comment: Great answer, thank you but over the time Yii2 has evolved and I've reallocated the "solution" to the simpler of the answers. Cheers.

Comment: I added this to ignore character case:  
```$query->andFilterWhere([
    'like',
    'LOWER(TableB.attrB1)',
     strtolower($this->getAttribute('TableB.attrB1'))
]); ```

Answer (score 3):

I'm stuck with this problem too, and my solution is rather different. I have two simple models:

Book:

```
class Book extends ActiveRecord
{
    ....

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'books';
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }
```

And Author:

```
class Author extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'authors';
    }

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::className(), ['author_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

But my search logic is in different model. And i didn't find how can i implement search without creating additional field `author_first_name`. So this is my solution:

```
class BookSearch extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $author_first_name;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'author_id'], 'integer'],
            [['title', 'author_first_name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Book::find()->joinWith(['author' => function($query) { $query->from(['author' => 'authors']);}]);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 50),
            'sort'=>[
                'attributes'=>[
                    'author_first_name'=>[
                        'asc' => ['author.first_name' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['author.first_name' => SORT_DESC],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        ....
        $query->andWhere(['like', 'author.first_name', $this->author_first_name]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

This is for creating table alias: `function($query) { $query->from(['author' => 'authors']);}`

And GridView code is:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'filter' => false,
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'author_first_name',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                    if ($model->author) {
                        $model->author->getFullName();
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
            'filter' => true,
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I will appreciate any critiques and advice.