# Filter setup for related model in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I am trying to setup the filter for related model in Yii2's [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) widget, but I am keep getting the error like the filter value must be an integer.

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992687/php-yii2-gridview-filtering-on-relational-value/). Now, I have a two models `Services.php` and `ServiceCharge.php`.

In `ServiceCharge.php` the relation is setup like:

```
public function getServiceName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Services::className(),['id'=>'service_name']);
    }
```

In the `ServiceChargeSearch.php` the code is like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\ServiceCharges;

/**
 * ServiceChargesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\ServiceCharges`.
 */
class ServiceChargesSearch extends ServiceCharges
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        // add related fields to searchable attributes
      return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['serviceName.services']);

    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['charges_cash', 'charges_cashless'], 'number'],
            [['id', 'serviceName.services', 'room_category'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = ServiceCharges::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['serviceName.services'] = [
        'asc' => ['serviceName.services' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['serviceName.services' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

$query->joinWith(['serviceName']); 

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
           // 'service_name' => $this->service_name,
            'room_category' => $this->room_category,
            'charges_cash' => $this->charges_cash,
            'charges_cashless' => $this->charges_cashless,
        ])
      ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'serviceName.services', $this->getAttribute('serviceName.services')]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

and in my Gridview it is setup like this:

```
[
                'attribute'=>'service_name',
                'value'=>'serviceName.services',

            ],
```

Which is showing the services name from the related model correctly.

I am not able to see what I am doing wrong, but the filter field for the attribute for service is not showing at all.

Comment: can u please post the complete php code in "ServiceChargeSearch.php". The error is due to the fact the validators are configured incorrectly

Comment: @BalajiViswanath - updated and added the full code for `serviceChargeSearch.php`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it is much simpler than it seems.

1. add the `column_name` to safe attribute.
   Note: this should be relation Name
2. add the join with query - like - `$query->joinWith(['serviceName','roomCategory']);`
3. add the filter condition like:

   ```
   ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'services.services', $this->service_name])
   ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'room_category.room_category', $this->room_category]);
   ```
4. if like to add sorting add the code like:

   ```
   $dataProvider->sort->attributes['service_name'] = [
       'asc'  => ['services.services' => SORT_ASC],
       'desc' => ['services.services' => SORT_DESC],
   ];
   $dataProvider->sort->attributes['room_category'] = [
       'asc'  => ['room_category.room_category' => SORT_ASC],
       'desc' => ['room_category.room_category' => SORT_DESC],
   ];
   ```

5 you should also set the relation name say `public $roomCategory`

That's it. Both sorting and filtering for related table works perfectly.

Note: Remove default validation like integer for related column and default filtering generated by `gii` otherwise it will generate an error.

Update on Latest version:

- Adding Public $attribute is not needed.
- Adding safe attribute for    relation is also not needed.
- but the attribute in your current model,    which you want filter is
  to added to safe attribute that is a must.
- and most importantly in your gridview, the related attribute has to
  be in closure format.

that is example

```
[
'attribute=>'attribute_name',
'value=function($data){
     return $data->relationname->related_table_attribute_name
}
],
```

remember it you are using `relation_name.related_table_attribute_name` filter somehow doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly comprehensive set of instructions [on the Yii Framework website](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculatedrelated-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0). The only thing to note is that the search model complains about the following lines, but everything appears to work as intended without them:

```
$this->addCondition(...);
```

For a model, PaymentEvent (table: subs_payment_event), which has a currency_id field linked to model Currency, this is the complete set of additional code (using the Basic template):

In the main model, PaymentEvent.php:

```
public function getCurrencyName()
{
    return $this->currency->name;
}
```

In the search model, PaymentEventSearch.php:

```
public $currencyName;
```

In its rules:

```
[['currencyName'], 'safe'],
```

In the attributes of its setSort statement, include:

```
'currencyName' => [
    'asc' => ['subs_currency.name' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['subs_currency.name' => SORT_DESC],
    'label' => 'Currency'
],
```

Before the grid filtering conditions:

```
$query->joinWith(['currency' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('subs_currency.name LIKE "%' . $this->currencyName . '%"');
    }]);
```

Finally, in the GridView columns array in the view (including my usual link across to the related model records):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'currencyName',
    'label' => 'Currency',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($data) {
            return Html::a($data->currency->name, ['/currency/' . $data->currency_id]);
        },
],
```

Comment: `Little Bobby Tables` says hi. Never concatenate SQL queries like that man...