# Search + Sort in related model in GridView (yii2)

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

first of all, I know there is a similar question here: [Filter setup for related model in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285084/filter-setup-for-related-model-in-gridview). I tried to follow that but that didn't do the trick.

I also checked different guides on how to go, but I'm still stuck.
For reference, I followed these guides here

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

However, I still don't have a search-field + sort-function in my view.

I used **gii** to create the CRUD-functionalities.

**My Manufacturers.php (Model):**

```
// basic model, nothing special here. 
// The following line was added to create a relation
public function getVendor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vendors::className(), ['vendor_id' =>   'vendor_id']);
}
```

**My ManufacturersSearch.php (Model):**

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Manufacturers;

/**
 * ManufacturersSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Manufacturers`.
 */
class ManufacturersSearch extends Manufacturers
{
    public $vendor;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['manufacturer_id', 'vendor_id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'vendor'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Manufacturers::find();
        $query->joinWith("vendor");

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['vendor_name'] = [
            // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
            // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
            'asc' => ['vendor.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['vendor.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        if (!$this->load($params) && $this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'manufacturer_id' => $this->manufacturer_id,
            'vendor_id' => $this->vendor_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'vendor.vendor', $this->vendor]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**And finally my view-file:**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'name',
        [
            'label' => 'Hauptlieferant',
            'value' => 'vendor.name',
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>
```

This is my current output:

[image: Correct names (instead of id's) - still not sortable]

So, it is kinda working, since instead of ID's, I'm getting the name (which is what I wanted). But for some reason, these fields are not sortable nor searchable.

> The table "manufacturers" **as well as** the table "vendors" has a column "**name**"

Thanks for any hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In ManufactuiresSearch you need also joinWith in filter

```
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

    $query->joinWith(['vendor' => function ($q) {
        $q->andFilterWhere(['like', 'vendor.vendor', $this->vendor]);
    }]);

    return $dataProvider;
```

Comment: unable to use `andFilterWhere` with `$q`

Comment: @MrFaisal  .. whitout see you code is impossible answer ..so .  post a new question with your code  and a clear explanation  of your problem  .. and eventually comment me the link