# yii2 grid view searching ,sorting ,filtering for two table

Tags: yii2

How to  searching ,sorting ,filtering for two  table in yii2 grid view? after generating from gii tool ,i got searching sorting for one table columns but i have  to apply  searching ,sorting ,filtering on columns of another table.

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'username',

            // 'account_activation_token',
             'email:email',
             'profile.name',
             [       
                'attribute' => 'name',
        'value' => 'profile.name',
        'enableSorting' => true,
         //here i want to use the filter option just like in yii 1.1 but i dont know how to use the textbox search in yii2.0 
        ],
            // 'usertype',
            // 'status',
            // 'created_at',
            // 'updated_at',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to use data from related records in another table?

Comment: Please take some effort to google it first. Here is the link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: @JoeMiller yes i am using data from another table and need to apply textbox searching on them and i already googled but there is no example for two table records.

Comment: @chinmay  i have done lot of goole here and use [       
                'attribute' => 'name',
        'value' => 'profile.name',
        'enableSorting' => true,
        ], this code, but i am not geet text box and sort

Comment: Can you show the code what you tried so far? Where exactly you are facing the problem.

Comment: @chinmay please see the above code i used for gridview need a textbox to search a name

Comment: @JoeMiller ,hello  if decrease my point that means you have to give me right answer.otherwise how can you deserve for decreasing my point.

Comment: @chinmay,hello  if decrease my point that means you have to give me right answer.otherwise how can you deserve for decreasing my point.

Comment: @santosh I don't actually have to do anything, especially if you're going to be rude to my attempts to help you. Goodbye.

Comment: this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992687/php-yii2-gridview-filtering-on-relational-value

Answer (score -1):

Try Using:

```
 [       
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'value' => 'profile.name',
        'enableSorting' => true,
        'filter' => function($model){
                return Html::activeTextInput($searchModel, $this->name),
         }
 ],
```